# For the ranking of the solver competition, What is the block height used to simulate and validate the settlements submitted by solvers?

Tags: cow-protocol

As a solver, when running a settlement simulation with call data for auction 123456, sometimes there is a successful simulation for that settlement, but when checking the solver competition ranking process, you encounter that the settlement simulation has failed. Why would it fail during the ranking process?

Answer (score 0):

For the solver competition ranking process simulation, if you are simulating in position 0 on tenderly, then you need to increment the block number by 1.

The solver competition ranking process simulates on latest block and when 123456 is the latest block on the node you are simulating, this means that such simulation is in position zero of block 123456 + 1.

*Note that this process will be deprecated once driver collocation is in place*